# Print left column number X number of times Excel

Tags: excel

[image]

I know the `=rept` function will repeat a certain number x y number of times, but the numbers are all on the same line, is there any way to get this to repeat on a new line every time?

the picture is just to get a good idea what i'm saying.

Comment: The picture you've provided isn't particularly illuminating. What output are you looking to get, given the input provided in the picture?

Comment: sorry.  the first number is the left column is to be repeated 15 times, on 15 different rows.  the second number is to be printed 13 times, each on a new row.

Comment: Oh, so the number on the left needs to insert itself (number on the right) times down the column. And it needs to insert new rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a range, type a number and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> and it will fill for you. Is that what you're looking to do?

---

### VBA

This VBA will take the active cell and copy it down x number of times when x is the cell next to the active cells

```
Sub InsertSome()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim n As Integer
    n = ActiveCell(, 2)
    For i = 1 To n
        ActiveCell.Copy
        ActiveCell.Insert shift:=xlDown
        ActiveCell(2, 2).Insert shift:=xlDown
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you need it to be inserted 1 less time because the active cell is part of the count, just change it to `For i=1 to (n-1)`

Comment: That works, yes.  But that requires the tedious task of making sure you select the correct range.  Can you select a range based on a value in the Excel?

Comment: @DarrinCecil added VBA that will do what you want